# Unusual plant identification

Tags: identification

[image][image][image]

We purchased this plant at an estate sale and hope you can identify it. They thought it was a corpse flower, but research shows it is not.
It's place of origin is unknown. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice the flat leaf-like structure on the stems and the alternating leaves of varied sizes.

Comment: This could be a sun depleted potato plant. The thin and flat leaves covering the stem of the leaves are characteristic.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the forum!

After a quick googling of "plant with mottled stalk" and looking at the images I was surprised to find that two that most caught my eye were indeed Amorphophallus.
I have never had the (dis)pleasure of seeing one in person, so I'm going by google, but [*Amorphophallus konjac*](http://wimastergardener.org/article/voodoo-lily-amorphophallus-konjac/) seems like a possibility.

My other guess, and would be an arisaema, but without a flower it would be very hard to identify which one.

I'm curious as to what made you decide it wasn't a corpse flower.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and research! Either the homeowner or the people running the estate sale labeled it as such. I'll look up the plant names you have posted to see what I have gotten myself into. Thanks again!